# iframe for token renew times out and we end up with path appended to redirect url

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

We are using adal-angular to protect our site.  On load, we have some expensive queries, so to avoid having this reload (and repeat the queries) in the iframe, we have a custom redirect page:

```
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init(
        {
            anonymousEndpoints: accessDeniedPages,              // Pages that are accessible when the user is not authenticated
            instance: 'https://[redacted]/',       // This is to differentiate Prod from Int environments
            tenant: '[redacted]',                  // This is the name of our AAD tenant
            clientId: clientId,                                   // This is our AAD app client id (not the Web App)
            endpoints: endpoints,                                 // These are the other AAD apps we can talk to (see above)
            redirectUri: frameRedirectUrl,
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage'                         // Specifies Local instead of Session storage
        }, $httpProvider);
```

Recently we have noticed a problem where, when the user goes to the site with expired tokens, the token renewal kicks in, but they are left either:

A)  On our redirect page with their route parameter appended:
https://localhost:44301/app/frameRedirect/frameRedirect.html#/reports/ instead of https://localhost:44301/#/reports/

B)  On the redirect url with the token appended
https://localhost:44301/app/frameRedirect/frameRedirect.html#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6...

I enabled verbose logging, and the first thing I noticed was that there were timeouts creating the iframe:

> Thu, 08 Mar 2018 23:05:35 GMT:1.0.17-VERBOSE: Loading frame has timed out after: 6 seconds for resource https://[redacted]

When I bumped up the timeout (from 6 seconds), things *seem* to be working (though getting into the repro state is always iffy).

I can't bump this up in production, however, as we are getting adal from CDN and not a local copy.

Questions:

- What would make this start timing out now (has been working for 2 years)
- Why are we ending on the redirect page with the path appended instead of being taken to the correct location?

Per the second item, I debugged and see that it is trying to go to that location with $window.location.href, but never seems to get there.

thanks,
~john